# Java special character validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to include `[]$:?\` in the validation below. I've tried to escape each but to no avail. How can I include them?

```
function validate_desc(val){
    if (val.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9,-. \\\\/(/)#/_/'\":]+\$")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a regex literal and not a string. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: Your title says "Java" and your tags say "JavaScript". Which is it? They have about as much in common as "Car" and "Carpet".

Comment: `-` must be at the end of the character class, `]` must be escaped